# Make Quicksight resource depend on an s3 bucket creation in AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I got a s3 bucket where that uploads a manifest file on creation in CDK.

This manifest file is then use by an Dataset in Quicksight. But my CDK deployment fails because the manifest file in S3 can't be found by QuickSight. So I want to add a `dependsOn` for the Quicksight resource.

```js
const quicksightBucket = new s3.Bucket(this, "userS3Bucket", {
            bucketName: "quicksight-bucket-user",
            blockPublicAccess: s3.BlockPublicAccess.BLOCK_ALL,
            versioned: true,
            removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
            autoDeleteObjects: true,
        })

        const bucketDeployment = new s3deploy.BucketDeployment(
            this,
            "bucketDeployment",
            {
                destinationBucket: quicksightBucket,
                sources: [
                    s3deploy.Source.asset("/Users/user/Downloads/housing"),
                ],
            }
        )

                const quicksightDatasource = new quicksight.CfnDataSource(
            this,
            "quicksight-datasource",
            {
                name: "quicksightdatasource",
                awsAccountId: "123123",
                dataSourceId: "7217623409123897423687",
                type: "S3",
                dataSourceParameters: {
                    s3Parameters: {
                        manifestFileLocation: {
                            bucket: quicksightBucket.bucketName,
                            key: "manifest.json",
                        },
                    },
                },
            }
        )

        quicksightDatasource.addDependsOn(bucketDeployment)
```

I'm getting an error like: `Argument of type 'Bucket' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CfnResource'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a dependency on the Bucket itself:

```js
quicksightDatasource.addDependency(
    quicksightBucket.node.defaultChild as s3.CfnBucket
);
```

That's probably not what you want, though.  That ensures the *bucket* exists before the QuickSight resource is created.  It doesn't ensure your `manifest.json` *data* are in the bucket.  To do that, instead add a dependency on the Custom Resource that's deployed by the `s3deploy.BucketDeployment`:

```js
quicksightDatasource.addDependency(
    bucketDeployment.node.tryFindChild("CustomResource")?.node.defaultChild as CfnCustomResource
);
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue.  When I run synth I get an error 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'shouldSynthesize')
    at CfnEnvironment.addDependency (C:\Users\d-          See below my code

Comment: otherResource.node.addDependency(deployment) worked for me. See comment by #moltar

Answer (score 0):

You need to depend on the deployed bucket, which is resolved only when the deployment is complete.

```js
quicksightDatasource.addDependency(bucketDeployment.deployedBucket)
```

> If you want to reference the destination bucket in another construct and make sure the bucket deployment has happened before the next operation is started, pass the other construct a reference to `deployment.deployedBucket`.

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_s3_deployment.BucketDeployment.html#deployedbucket